# Proper acceleration along perpendicular directions

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration

Let's take an object (all times mentioned in this problem are proper times). There is a constant  proper acceleration
"$a$" on this object in the x-direction for time $t, 0\leq t \leq \tau$. After this, there is the same proper acceleration in the y-direction for time t, $\tau \leq t \leq 2\tau$. What is the velocity of the object in the laboratory frame? My approach was to first find the velocity $v$ at proper time $\tau$, then in that moving frame (moving with $v$ in the x-direction) calculate the velocity at time
$2\tau$. But this doesn't seem like a correct idea.

PS: Can the above idea be extended to find the speed of object at t = $4\tau$, provided the proper accelerations are in the -x and -y directions for equal time intervals $\tau$ after t = $2\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity of an object undergoing constant proper acceleration $a$ is $$v=\tanh\left(\frac{a \tau}{ c}\right)$$

With that then we use the velocity addition formula for non-parallel velocities: $$\mathbf u =\frac{1}{1 + \frac{\mathbf u' \cdot \mathbf v}{c^2}}\left[\mathbf v +
\frac{\mathbf u'}{\gamma_v} + \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\gamma_v}{1+\gamma_v}(\mathbf u' \cdot \mathbf v)\mathbf v\right]$$

In this scenario $\mathbf v$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf u’$ so this simplifies to $$\mathbf u =\mathbf v +
\frac{\mathbf u'}{\gamma_v} $$

Comment: I myself got this, but if I try a general Lorentz transformation approach (I take an instantaneous inertial frame and apply the definition of proper acceleration) then I get that the x-component of velocity in the t=2T case is different from velocity in x direction for t=T, which is contradictory to the above mentioned result.

Comment: Sounds like you are running into this issue: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation

Comment: Thanks for this. But while I understand that after applying successive non-parallel Lorentz boosts, the frame of the spaceship will rotate wrt to the lab frame, I don’t see how that invalidates my previous case. Effectively, if I always take my instantaneous inertial frame to be parallel with the lab frame and apply the Lorentz boost (gdt velocity in y-direction), I get that dV_x is proportional to V_x and V_y, which are not zero for the spaceship between T and 2T. This implies that in the lab frame, there is a changing velocity of spaceship in the x-direction between T and 2T.

Comment: In fact, my original question(which my asked question is a sub part of) applies 4 such proper accelerations for four time intervals, with a counter-clockwise rotation each time, and says that at time T and 4T, the speeds are the same, which seems like a Thomas precession.

Comment: It isn’t “invalidated”. It is just different. It is perfectly legitimate to specify it either way, but they are different specifications because of Wigner rotation

Comment: Ah I understand. So my picture of instantaneous frames having axes parallel to the lab frame is just different from the actual wigner rotated instantaneous inertial frame. In that sense, for proper acceleration along y-axis, is that along the wigner rotated frame? Also, can I iteratively repeat this process for say finding velocity at time t = 3T, where the spaceship had proper acceleration in the -x direction from time 2T to 3T